# MapKit annotations only show after a delay in foreground (or going to Home screen and back)

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, foreground

I am loading an array of custom annotations from a server and want to add them to the map using the following code. The annotations only appear on the map after 10 seconds or so when the app is in the foreground. However, they appear immediately when I go to the home screen (app is then in background) and then back to the app. 
How can I get these annotations to show without delay when the app is in the foreground?

I get the custom annotations array from a server and try to add them to the map as follows:

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active {
self.myMap.showAnnotations(self.these_new_pins, animated: true)
}
```

My mapView viewForAnnotation looks like this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
                return nil
            }

            // ... otherwise continue executing function
            var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("pin")

            if pinView == nil {
                pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
                pinView!.canShowCallout = true
                pinView!.alpha = 0.97
                pinView!.centerOffset.y = -23

            }

            else {

                pinView!.annotation = annotation
            }


            let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation

            // Pin color varies (user green, server blue)
                pinView!.image = UIImage(named: cpa.pin_image)

            // Add detail button to right callout
                var calloutButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as! UIButton
                var btnimage = UIImage(named: cpa.pin_btnimage)!

                    calloutButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
                    calloutButton.setBackgroundImage(btnimage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton

            // Add detail button to left callout
                var optionsButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as! UIButton
                var btnimage_options = UIImage(named: cpa.pin_btnimage_options)

                    optionsButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
                    optionsButton.setBackgroundImage(btnimage_options, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                pinView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = optionsButton


            return pinView
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. It's look like you call the "showAnnotations" not from the main thread.

Comment: Spot on Mozilla! This fixed it!            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active {
                                        
                                        self.myMap.showAnnotations(self.these_new_pins, animated: true)
                                        
                                    }
                                        }

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to call the showAnnotations from the main thread (thanks Mozilla). Here is the code to do it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active { self.myMap.showAnnotations(self.these_new_pins, animated: true) } }
```